# I was researching on time travel and got an idea. Is free fall a case of time travel?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, observers, free-fall, time-travel

A person standing in a  huge lift which is free falling.

**Observation:** for that person gravity will be *relatively* zero.

As we know the weaker the gravity is the faster time flows and stronger the gravity is slower the time flows( eg case of black hole)

So is it case of time travel? As for the person gravity is relatively zero so he would be experiencing time very fast..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. Your [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) depends on the gravitational potential at your location, it doesn't matter if you're in freefall or if you're at rest, resisting the gravitational field.

BTW, the gravitational time dilation on Earth's surface is quite small. According to that Wikipedia article, a clock on Earth's surface loses about 2.19 seconds per *century* due to the Earth's gravity.